# TokenMismatchException error after dockerizing laravel project

Tags: php, apache, docker, laravel-4, docker-compose

I have a laravel4 project with php5.4 and apache up and running with no problems after dockerizing it, it hits

> Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException

Is there any dependency or module or anything I should lookup for to overcome this problem ??

PS: I enabled mod_session and i don't know if it is relevant or not and I'm using docker-compose for mysql

Comment: where is the session being stored (is it db or file storage)? have you tried on incognito mode to access? i could only think of your cookie is mismatching with the one on the docker image.

Comment: stored in db and yes I tried incognito mode, same result

Comment: can you add the stacktrace into the question?

Comment: That won't be possible.
Is there something I can lookup for ??

Comment: in storage folder, if i remember correctly it had logs on it. i hope we can salvage some info from it.. its kind of hard, i could only think that the cookie and the session id stored is mismatching when submitting some post request.